# TailwindCSS + NextJS: Integrating with PostCSS and IE11 support (custom properties)

Tags: next.js, postcss, tailwind-css, autoprefixer, custom-properties

According to the docs, tailwind states it [supports ie11](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/browser-support/#app).

...yet it uses [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) that are [not supported by ie11](https://caniuse.com/#search=custom%20properties).

We're attempting to use this in a minimal nextjs project with the following `postcss.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    'postcss-import',
    'tailwindcss',
    'autoprefixer',
    ['postcss-custom-properties', { preserve: false }]
  ]
};
```

The only css file we're importing:

```css
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';
```

The line `['postcss-custom-properties', { preserve: false }]` appears to not be doing anything. Both with the defaults and that one.

Obviously, since ie 11 doesn't support custom properties, stuff like the `transform` utility are completely ignored.

Anyone have any suggestions for this? I've been spending way too much time on trying to get this to work :|

Comment: Hi @AltruisticSoftware, did you ever end up solving this? I find myself in the same situation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still experimenting which is the best value but the `target` attribute in your `postcss.config.js` is the responsible, set it to `ie11` and all the custom css properties will be removed.

The `target` property isn't documented but I've found [this issue](https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/1635) explaining the situation. If you are using browserlist, try using

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'browserslist',
}
```